# Why does Dirac bilinear $\bar{\psi}\sigma^{\mu\nu}\psi$ is frequently written with a factor of $i$?

Tags: conventions, dirac-equation, complex-numbers, dirac-matrices

The tensor Dirac bilinear $\bar{\psi}\sigma^{\mu\nu}\psi$ has the matrix tensor $\sigma^{\mu\nu}=\frac{i}{2}\left[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\right]$.

I can understand that the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ is a convenience for normalization. Using the properties of gamma-matrices one cans show that $\left[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\right]=2\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu-2\eta^{\mu\nu}$. However, I cannot understand why there is a factor of $i$ in $\sigma^{\mu\nu}$? What is it's purpose?

Comment: Factors of $i$ after often chose for Hermiticity reasons. It unfortunately is one of the places where notation convention in physics diverges from the convention in mathematics (where Hermiticity is not an inherently important property).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "$i$" makes $i[\gamma^i,\gamma^j]/4$, with $i,j$ referring to the space coordinates $x, y$ or $z$, Hermitian. Hermitian operators are often preferred as generators of rotations. For $i[\gamma^0, \gamma^i]/4$ remains skew  Hermitian, but Lorentz boosts are not unitary anyway.

Not everyone uses the $i$, and some write $[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]/(4i)$. I prefer to write
$$
\sigma^{\mu\nu} = \frac 1 4 [\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu],
$$
but i am in a minority here. I also prefer  $1/4$ rather that $1/2$ as the numerical coefficient as it is $\sigma_i/2$ that is the rotation generator.

Whichever convention you decide to use, you should always spell it our for your reader.